# Call logs loading slow

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, calllog

Hi I am developing an android app where I am trying to display the call logs on a list view.

```
private void getCallDetails() 
{
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, "date DESC");

    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int nameid = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

        while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
            //type of call
            String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );

            //call date
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)));

            //call time
            SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String timeString = time.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)));

            String calldur = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            int sec =  Integer.parseInt(calldur);

            //converting seconds 
            String dur = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", sec/3600, (sec%3600)/60, (sec%60));

            String name = managedCursor.getString(nameid);
            if(name == null)
            {
                map.put(contactName, "Unknown");
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(contactName, name); 
            }

            int dir = 0;
            int imageId = 0;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
            switch( dircode )
            {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = R.drawable.outgoing;
                imageId = R.drawable.clock;
                callDuration = dur;
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir =  R.drawable.incoming;
                imageId = R.drawable.clock;
                callDuration = dur;
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = R.drawable.missed;
                callDuration = " ";
                imageId = R.drawable.empty;
                break;
            }
            map.put(phone, phNumber);
            map.put(DateOfCall,dateString );    
            map.put(TimeOfCall,timeString );    
            dirType = String.valueOf(dir);
            map.put(typeofCall,dirType );
            map.put(durationOfCall, callDuration);

            clkimgId = String.valueOf(imageId);
            map.put(imgId,clkimgId);
            map.put(image,contactID);

            DetailsList.add(map);
        }

    managedCursor.close();  
}
```

I am calling the above getCallDetails() in doInBackground and loading to adapter in onPostExecute as

```
    adapter = new Adapter(Cal.this, DetailsList);   
    callList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But this loading is too slow. How can I fix it? Not sure where I am going wrong.

Please Help.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it gradually get slower? Are their a lot of records? Is it consistent? Does anything seem to trigger it?

Comment: No it doesnt get slower gradually and There are lot of records. For what you are saying Consistent and triggering ? After getting all the records listview is dispalyed

Comment: @sanjana `But this loading is too slow.` What do you mean by slow?

Comment: It takes like 10 -15 seconds to dispaly

Comment: Actually looking at other call logs apps like: Call Log monitor, CallHistory - They are super fast in the loading. I just don't need to wait for the logs to open. They are instant... I am not sure where I am wrong?

Comment: @sanjana have you solved this problem because I have same problem while loading logs please help

Answer (score 0):

public class CallSmsSafeService extends Service {

```
private class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            String mode = dao.findMode(incomingNumber);
            if("1".equals(mode)||"3".equals(mode)){
                Log.i(TAG,"这是黑名单号码，挂断电话。。。");
                //监视呼叫记录的生成，如果呼叫记录产生了。删除呼叫记录。
                Uri url = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
                getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(url, true, new CallLogObserver(new Handler(), incomingNumber));

            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private class CallLogObserver extends ContentObserver{
    private String incomingNumber;
    public CallLogObserver(Handler handler, String incomingNumber) {
        super(handler);
        this.incomingNumber = incomingNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(this);
        deleteCalllog(incomingNumber);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    receiver = null;
    tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    listener = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * 清除呼叫记录
 * @param incomingNumber
 */
public void deleteCalllog(String incomingNumber) {
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri url = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    resolver.delete(url, "number=?", new String[]{incomingNumber});
}
```

}

Comment: you did so much thing in your while action